# Haskell Function to multiply elements in a list

Tags: list, haskell

```
dobb[] = []
dobb (x:xs) = [x * 2| x<- xs]
```

I am really new to haskell and started learning it this week. I want to create a function that multiplies each element in a list by 2. So the list would go from [1,2,3] to [2,4,6]. The code I have works fine, except it skips the first element of the list and goes from  [1,2,3] to [4,6]. How can I make the code multiply the first element as well?

```
[x*2 | x<-[1..5]]
```

I've found this line that does what I am looking for, but I dont understand how to go from this line of code and convert it to a function that works for all lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the pattern `(x:xs)` then you unpack the list such that `x` is the *head* (first item) of the list, and `xs` is the *tail* (remaining items) of that list. For a list `[1,4,2,5]`, `x` will thus refer to `1`, and `xs` to `[4,2,5]`.

In the list comprehension, you then use `x <- xs` as a generator, and thus you enumerate over the *remaining* elements. The `x` in the list comprehension is furthermore *not* the head of the list, but a more locally scoped variable.

You can work with list comprehension and work on the entire list, so:

```
dobb :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
dobb xs = [x * 2| x <- xs]
```

We can also work with [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to perform the same operation on the elements:

```
dobb :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
dobb = map (2*)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D

Is it correct that "Num a => [a]" means that there is a list of numbers? If that is the case, what does the last "[a]->[a]" mean?

Comment: @AndersStene: the signature is `[a] -> [a]` since we are given a list of elements, and we return a list of elements of the same type. The `Num a` is a type constraints that specifies that the type of the elements should be an instance of the `Num` typeclass, and thus be a number.

Comment: Great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll address your last question,

> how to go from this line of code,
>
> ```
>       [x*2 | x <- [1..5]]
> ```
>
> and convert it to a function that works for all lists[?]

This is known as generalization and is achieved by abstraction. First we name it,

```
foo = [x*2 | x <- [1..5]]
```

then we name that arbitrary piece of data we used as an example to work on,

```
foo = let {xs = [1..5]} in [x*2 | x <- xs]
```

and then we abstract over it by *removing* that arbitrary piece of data in the internal definition, letting it become the function *parameter* instead, to be specified by this, now, function's callers:

```
foo        xs           =  [x*2 | x <- xs]
```

and there it is, the general function working on all lists, doing the same thing as it did on the specific example we used at first.